# P4JAVA Equivalent to p4 changes -m1 @workspace

Tags: perforce, p4api.net, p4java

I need to find out what is the last revision Synced to my workspace but using the P4JAVA API, Any help??

Comment: What have you tried already? I believe the correct method is `getChangelists` on the `iServer` interface.

Comment: Hi, i have updated my question with more details on what i tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for `FileSpecBuilder` you can include a rev specifier with the path, so if you change this:

```
makeFileSpecList("//depotname/path/...")
```

to this:

```
makeFileSpecList("@workspace")
```

it seems like that ought to do the trick.